# Typescript: use 2 class in the 3rd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to use 2 class with different functions. what happens is it does not execute the function.

For example I want to do something like `C.getMove('action1').run()` it does not execute the `run()` function

```
class A {
  function runForward() {
    // do something here
  }
  function runBackward() {
    // do something here
  }
}

class B {
  function run() {
    // do something here
  }
  function walk() {
    // do something here
  }
}

class C {
  public static getMove(action: string) {
    if(action === 'action1') return new B()
    if(action === 'action2') return new A()
    return new B()
  }
}
```

I think I am missing something but I don't know what it is

Comment: Class A doesn't have run method. It has runForward. Prefer using interfaces.

Comment: First, delete the `function` keywords in the classes for it to be valid. Then, you could use `(C.getMove('action1') as B).run();` to let it compile - but this is **very bad practice** - if your method returns `A | B` the two classes should be compatible, e.g., share a common interface. Otherwise, you could create separate methods like `getMove1` that returns type `B` and `getMove2` that returns type `A`

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to go about this. Firstly, using the  `function` keyword to declare function in `class` is inappropriate in OOP. hence,Take a look at the code below

```
interface Methods{
  run(): void
  //add methods here
}

class A {
  static runForward() {
    // do something here
  }
  static runBackward() {
    // do something here
  }
}

class B {
   static run() {
    // do something here
    console.log("something is out")
  }
  static walk() {
    // do something here
  }
}

class C{
  public static getMove(action: string) {
    if(action === 'action1') return B;
    if(action === 'action2') return A;
    return B;
  }
}

(C.getMove('action1') as Methods).run()
```

First, i removed the `function` before the `methods` in the class, then i made all the methods `run(), walk()...` static. Also, take note of the `interface Methods` so as to let `C.getMove('action1')` aware of the function `run()` in the class `B()` .

Let me know if anything.